How to access dumped cache in Symfony
I use Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache component to save the application configuration. I found the next script for dumping it:

$cachePath =  dirname(__DIR__) . '/cache/config.php';
$configPath = dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/config.json';
$cache = new ConfigCache($cachePath, true);

$dirs = array(__DIR__);
$locator = new FileLocator($dirs);
$loader = new ConfigLoader($locator);

$configValues = $loader->load($configPath);
$resource = new FileResource($configPath);

$processor = new Processor();
$configuration = new Configuration();

$processedConfiguration = $processor->processConfiguration(
    $configuration,
    $configValues
);

$cache->write(serialize($processedConfiguration), array($resource->getResource));


As the result, I got cache/config.php and cache/config.php.meta with strange syntax:
a:3:{s:11:"projectName";s:20:"practice/symfony/006";s:8:"telegram";a:2:{s:5:"token";s:46:"token";s:7:"chatIds";a:1:{i:0;i:11111111;}}s:6:"rabbit";a:4:{s:4:"host";s:8:"rabbitmq";s:4:"port";i:5432;s:4:"user";s:7:"symfony";s:8:"password";s:14:"password";}}


Now I'm trying to read these values inside the service factory, but I have no idea how to do it
I was trying to find the method to inspect values of different cache pools, but symfony allows only get and hasItem methods.
